# List full of rows of db data; how to load fields to labels?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, oop

I'm restructuring a practice project to convert to n-tier and OO, and I've hit a snag. I have 7 products, each with multiple fields, and a submission may have 0-7 products (no redundant instances). I store all the field data for all products with a relevant submission Id in List, which is a nested object inside the Submission object. All that to say, how do I pull the specific fields out of this list and load the labels on my page with them?

Example: Submission with Id 109 has Product EPL, and one field, Coverage, has a value of 800. I want label LblEplCov to contain that value. Code below.

**data layer for products**

```
  SqlCommand FidCmd = new SqlCommand(FiduciaryQuery, conn);
    SqlDataReader FidRead = new SqlDataReader();
    FidRead = FidCmd.ExecuteReader();

    Fiduciary TempFid = new Fiduciary();
    TempFid.Entity1 = FidRead.GetString(0);
    TempFid.PrimEx1 = FidRead.GetInt32(1);
    TempFid.Limit1 = FidRead.GetInt32(2);
    TempFid.SIR1 = FidRead.GetInt32(3);
    TempFid.Att1 = FidRead.GetInt32(4);
    TempFid.Premium1 = FidRead.GetInt32(5);
    TempFid.Sublim1 = FidRead.GetInt32(6);

    TempProdList.Add(TempFid);


    SqlCommand CrimeCmd = new SqlCommand(CrimeQuery, conn);

    SqlDataReader dr = null;
    List<Product> lstProduct = new List<Product>();

    dr = CrimeCmd.ExecuteReader();

    CrimeFidelity TempCrime = new CrimeFidelity();
    TempCrime.Entity1 = dr.GetString(0);
    TempCrime.Employees1 = dr.GetInt32(1);
    TempCrime.PrimEx1 = dr.GetInt32(2);
    TempCrime.LimA1 = dr.GetInt32(3);
    TempCrime.DedA1 = dr.GetInt32(4);
    TempCrime.PremA1 = dr.GetInt32(5);
    TempCrime.LimB1 = dr.GetInt32(6);
    TempCrime.DedB1 = dr.GetInt32(7);
    TempCrime.PremB1 = dr.GetInt32(8);

    TempProdList.Add(TempCrime);

    return TempProdList;
```

**Business layer**

```
    public static class ProductService
{
    public static List<Product> getProductById(string x)
    {
        return ProductDatabaseLayer.GetProductsById(x);       
    }    
}
```

**presentation layer**

```
    Submission sub = SubmissionService.getSubmissionByID(x);
    Customer cust = CustomerService.getCustomerById(sub.CustomerId1.ToString());
    Broker bro = BrokerService.getBrokerById(sub.BrokerId1.ToString());
    sub.Products1 = ProductService.getProductById(sub.SubmissionId1.ToString());
```

//Note: I imagine I would use an if !null block to determine whether a product is attached to the submission, but if there's a better way feel free to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to understand your question, but I think you are looking for ways to dynamically build your user interface from a data-source.

If so, try using Repeaters

```
<asp:Repeater ID="InfrastructureRepeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:CheckBox ID="InfrastructureCheckbox" Text='<%#Eval("InfrastructureName") %>'
        runat="server" />                           
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

eg. You bind your datasource to the repeater and specify a template. It is also possible to access your items in the code behind like so:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in InfrastructureRepeater.Items)
{
  CheckBox infrastructureCheckBox = item.FindControl("InfrastructureCheckBox") as CheckBox;
 //Do something here
}
```